# difference between unordered_map<const T, int> and map<const T, int>

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:

private:    
    // unordered_map<string, int> mapStrInt;       // Case 1: OK
    // unordered_map<const string, int> mapStrInt; // Case 2: Fail
    // map<string, int> mapStrInt;                 // Case 3: OK
    // map<const string, int> mapStrInt;           // Case 4: OK
};
```

Question> Why `Case 2` is not legal?

```
template < class Key,                                    // unordered_map::key_type
           class T,                                      // unordered_map::mapped_type
           class Hash = hash<Key>,                       // unordered_map::hasher
           class Pred = equal_to<Key>,                   // unordered_map::key_equal
           class Alloc = allocator< pair<const Key,T> >  // unordered_map::allocator_type
           > class unordered_map;
            template < class Key,                                     // map::key_type
           class T,                                       // map::mapped_type
           class Compare = less<Key>,                     // map::key_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >    // map::allocator_type
           > class map;
```

Based on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/unordered_map:47,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of 'struct std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int>, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>':
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1402:10:   required from 'struct std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int>, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<const std::basic_string<char> >, std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >'
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable.h:174:11:   required from 'class std::_Hashtable<const std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<const std::basic_string<char> >, std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >'
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/unordered_map.h:100:18:   required from 'class std::unordered_map<const std::basic_string<char>, int>'
main.cpp:11:38:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1070:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >'
     struct _Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _H1, _H2,
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/basic_string.h:3033:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/string:52,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12: error: declaration of 'struct std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >'
     struct hash;
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/unordered_map:47,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1070:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >'
     struct _Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _H1, _H2,
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/basic_string.h:3033:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/string:52,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12: error: declaration of 'struct std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >'
     struct hash;
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/unordered_map:47,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1082:53: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >'
       using __ebo_h1 = _Hashtable_ebo_helper<1, _H1>;
                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/basic_string.h:3033:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/string:52,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12: error: declaration of 'struct std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >'
     struct hash;
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/unordered_map:47,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1082:53: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >'
       using __ebo_h1 = _Hashtable_ebo_helper<1, _H1>;
                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/basic_string.h:3033:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/string:52,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12: error: declaration of 'struct std::hash<const std::basic_string<char> >'
     struct hash;
            ^
```

== Updated Working code based on the comments ==

```
struct HashConstString
{
    long operator()(const string& str) const {
        return hash<string>()(str);
    }
};

class Solution {
public:

private:    
    unordered_map<const string, int, HashConstString> mapStrInt; // Case 2: Now it works
};
```

Comment: Well. The compiler will tell. It will probably try things with const strings that can't be done with const strings. Like, you know, assigning them

Comment: I want to know why it is not legal and I don't want to depend on compiler.

Comment: @sehe: One of my compilers accepts it, the other complains that `hash<const string>` isn't defined. That's not enough to tell me whether or not it's valid.

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks for an interesting data point

Comment: @q0987:  You might need to get deep into the Standard here.

Comment: Based on the map property, I don't see the value of use `const key`, since you are not allowed to change the key of a map.

Comment: The question body is rather verbose now. I think it was better before. Can we have that back? Perhaps with just the error as you mentioned it in comments above. Sometimes the whole lot of them is useful but I don't think that this is one of those times, and the question was quite good when it was generic and to-the-point. :)

Answer (score 6):

From 21.6 we learn that four string-related hash functions are provided by the language:

```
template <> struct hash<string>;
template <> struct hash<u16string>;
template <> struct hash<u32string>;
template <> struct hash<wstring>;
```

Then from 23.5.2 we learn that the default hash for `unordered_map` is `hash<Key>` or in this case `hash<const std::string>`. Previously we learned that the implementation is not required to provide such a hash, so your code is not guaranteed to compile.

```
template <class Key,
class T,
class Hash = hash<Key>,
class Pred = std::equal_to<Key>,
class Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> > >
class unordered_map;
```

You can either use `std::string` as your key OR specify the hash function as `hash<std::string>` instead of relying on the default template parameter.

Comment: [Here's](http://ideone.com/HsB0hx) an example of both creating a `hash<const string>` specialization and using the `hash<string>` hash function.

Comment: +1: Spot on and without all the mess that I made. :)

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: `int main(void)` Yuck! ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Meh, force of habit from compatibility with C code.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: I understand. Sometimes I wish I didn't.